# finding the slope difference between two lines using python

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to seek a point leading to a slope difference of two lines.
[image]
As the figure shows, the slope of blue line changed at a specific day in January. So I am wondering what method I could use to find the specific day.
The data associated with the leak flow rate difference at each day in January is:

```
January = [-2.9870608333329756, 9.60849499999955, -9.11726166666682, 4.096632499999828, -1.8730966666662994, -5.278147500000216, 2.3465549999999666, -1.8635066666655575, 0.05206749999939575, 6.58928249999957, 11.687810833333572, -2.8625875000000747, 16.081065000000308, -6.094237500000247, 20.145450833333427, 6.806942499999877, 4.190984166666567, 21.902566666666814, 5.091000833333965, 25.374861666666163, 2.369847499999878, 29.525841666667134, 7.578364166667029, 22.980054166667685, -5.150730833334535, 0.6434674999997014, -2.256800000000169, 2.55019166666699, 0.3871808333329909, -3.583929166665257, 5.430872500000078]
```

Comment: The slope is simply the change in value over time - assuming your time steps are regular, that's just a series of differences then. What exactly is your question? In the example data you provided, what exactly is the relevant day? And why did you omit the date/time information from the data?

Comment: This seems to be a math question an therefore off-topic.

Comment: you can use [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) from SciPy